# Why does the php reference in a loop not point to the same place?

Tags: php

I am trying to understand references (=&) in PHP.
In this simple example it seems to behave inconsistently.

```
$a =& $b;
var_dump($a); //null
var_dump($b); //null


$my_array = ['ha'];
foreach($my_array as $key){
    $a =& $a[$key];
    echo "$key<br/>";
    var_dump($a); //null
    var_dump($b); //['ha'=>null]
}
```

Since both $a and $b should be pointing to the same place how is $a becoming null, while $b is becoming an array? If $a is changed, shouldn't $b also be changed to be the same? The logic seems inconsistent unless I'm completely misunderstanding assignment by reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the code inside the `foreach()` function. You assign `$a[$key]` to `$a` when `a[$key]` doesn't exist.

I rewrote the code and it's working correctly.

```
$a =& $b;
var_dump($a); //null
var_dump($b); //null

$my_array = ['ha'];
foreach($my_array as $key){
    echo "Key: ". $key ."\n"; // Key: ha
    $a = $key;
    var_dump($a); // string(2) "ha"
    var_dump($b); // string(2) "ha" 
}
```

Comment: I understand that the $a[$key] doesn't exist and is NULL, but if it doesn't exist, how is $b (which is the same as $a) set to an array? I'm not so much trying to get the code to work as understand the logic behind the code.